# two open graph images (facebook size and google size)

Tags: facebook, google-api, share, facebook-opengraph

How could I include open graph images *(two different ones; two different sizes)*

For both Facebook sharer and google sharer? .. via META open graph method.

Comment: Why do you want two different sizes?

Comment: Because facebook allows for larger size... google requires smaller.

Comment: I'm not aware of +Snippets having a max size and in fact [article rendering](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/article-rendering) a bigger than standard image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to do something on your side to detect which crawler (Google / Facebook) is accessing the URL and provide different metadata to each - it should work fine provided the metadata given to each crawler is consistent, but requires you to keep track of different User Agent headers, etc, sent by each site's crawler